# Alternative to Observer Pattern

Tags: multithreading, performance, oop, design-patterns, observer-pattern

Does anyone know of an alternative to the Observer a.k.a. Listener pattern?
I'm interested in something that would work well in an asynchronous 
environment.

The problem I'm facing is that I have an application which uses this 
pattern a lot, which is not a bad thing per se, but it becomes a bottleneck as the number of listeners increases. Combined with threading primitives (mutexes, critical sections - of course in my specific environment) the hit on performance is really bad.

Comment: Do the listeners work in parallel or serially?

Comment: I think any alternatives would be hugely dependent on what the specific cases were.

Comment: @ericgorr Cannot give more specifics. I'm really interested in general alternatives to the pattern; I'll figure out myself, hopefully, the one suitable to my particular situation. Don't take it the wrong way but I just don't think the specifics will help in any way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about [Message Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue)?

Comment: This might be a good the solution, although, so I read, it comes with its own headaches. I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: I've seen message queues  usually best served as message passing mechanism for the actor model.

Answer (score 3):

If there are too many observers, so the thread being observed is not making any progress, then it might be wise to reverse the relationship. Rather than have the observed thread call out to each and every observer, it may be better to have the observers wait on something like a condition variable or event associated with the observed thread. The observer code can then block, waiting for the condition variable to be signalled. The observed thread can then just signal the condition variable rather than calling into the observers; the observers can notice the signal and process the consequences in their own time.

Comment: This sounds good but it's more of a revamped Observer. Anyway I would have to share the condition object and the associated mutex with every observer, wouldn't I? Or to find a way around that. Also the observer thread might need to do something else besides just waiting for the condition to be signaled. And to top that I might have observers(group of observers) that do not run in their own thread. Anyway it's an alternative to be considered. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you would need every observer to know about the condition variable and mutex. Alternatively you could have one per observer, and have the observed thread notify each in turn. Or, you could have a message queue per observer, so the observed thread just posts messages rather than signalling.

Comment: If some of your observers aren't threaded, then you could just start a new thread to handle them. If they aren't thread-safe then you have bigger problems in a multithreaded app.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at it if reducing listeners in your code is your primary objective [Jeffrey Richter and his AsyncEnumerator](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/charles/jeffrey-richter-and-his-asyncenumerator). This technique makes asynchronous programmin look more like synchronous.

> With this technique your single method could issue an Asynch call and resto fo the method act as an event handler, therefore whole of the invokation and event listener code could be clubbed as one fucntion.

Comment: This is very specific to C# and it depends on some C# compiler "magic". I was looking for something that would not depend on a certain language's features.

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives from me: using actor model (like akka framework) or using executor to limit the parallelization. Executor is basically just a thread pool which will limit the number of thread and reuse finished threads.

Comment: Executor - is it the Java one? I'm not using Java and I was interested in an language agnostic solution. As for the Actor Model, it looks interesting but it would require a complete change in paradigm for my application - giving up completely the shared memory model I don't think would fit in my specific situation. Anyway I'll document a little bit more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without a more concrete description but the [Mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) is related and can be used when the number of communicating objects starts to proliferate.  You could implement some policy to co-ordinate the activities a more structured way within these.